# In which language are the device trees in Linux are developed?

Tags: linux, device-tree

From the book Device Tree for Dummies by Petazzoni, I read that `The Device Tree is really a hardware description language.`

Is it true? Otherwise, in which language are the device trees developed?

Comment: Linux is implemented almost entirely in C. I can't imagine that the device tree code is any different.

Comment: @Barmar device tree is data, not code.

Comment: @n.m. I thought he was talking about the kernel code that processes the device tree.

Answer (score 4):

Device Tree is a proper name of a description language. Recall that a language is by definition a set of strings. A device tree is a particular string that belongs to the Device Tree language.

Strictly speaking there are two closely related languages: the source language (DTS or device tree source, more suitable for humans) and the bytecode language (DTB or device tree blob, more suitable for machines). They are fully equivalent. Developers  normally describe hardware in the source language, then convert it to the binary form using the tool called DTC (device tree compiler). DTC can also do the reverse conversion.